# I can't get the props.match.params.id. It's said props is undefined

Tags: reactjs

I've tried to get the *id* from the URL (with props.match.params.id) and pass it into a variable to reuse it. But props is undefined. I don't know why.

Anyone can see if I've done something wrong?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function Recipes() {
  const [recipes, setRecipes] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const id = props.match.params.id;
    const getRecipes = async () => {
      const url = `http://localhost:8000/user/recipes/${id}`;
      const result = await axios.get(url);

      setRecipes(result.data);
      console.log("test", recipes);
    };
    getRecipes();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {recipes.map(recipe => (
        <p>{recipe.title}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you should need to make use of `params` hook to get the data. Check out https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Hooks/useparams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you **forgot to add props** in your functional component :

You can solve the error **"It's said props is undefined"**

---

By Change this :

```
export default function Recipes() {
```

TO

```
export default function Recipes(props) {
```

Comment: i thought originally the match object came from the this.props in a React Class. So passing props into Recipes is not a valid answer? Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 9):

You need to make use of the `useParams` hook from `react-router-dom` for this instead.

Try this:

```
...
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Recipes() {
  ...
  const { id } = useParams()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    ...
  }, [id])
  ...
}
```

Comment: I've got that error :  Line 15:22:  React Hook "useParams" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks.

Comment: My bad, updated the question. Just move the `useParams` line above the `useEffect` and you should be sorted :)

Comment: import { useParams } from 'react-roouter-dom' -> should actually be  'react-router-dom', yes?

Comment: @JollyGood good catch, I've updated it :)

Answer (score 0):

Ah! I think you forget it add props as a param to you component. This is something I do very often.

Your component should be like this

```
export default function Recipes(props) {

//Your content

}
```